# Make system tray apps start up before going to the desktop

Tags: windows-8, boot, desktop, start-screen

I have a couple of apps that start up and appear in the system tray. The one I'm really interested in is Steam.

What I've found is that if I **turn on the PC and login**, but **don't go to the desktop**, steam (always?) isn't started. Only once I click to go to the desktop does it start up.

Is there any setting/configuration I can change to get apps such as this to not require me to actually go to the desktop before they start/appear in the sys tray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[StartIsBack](http://startisback.com/) modifies the Startup Order, so the desktop applications are loaded faster. This should solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I havent tried this on Windows 8, but you can try running Steam as a service.  There are many different methods of doing this.  Here is one [example](http://www.howtogeek.com/50786/using-srvstart-to-run-any-application-as-a-windows-service/).  To find other options, just Google "running program as service."  I dont know how well these methods work in Windows 8.

You may just want to wait for a new version of Steam that supports the Modern UI interface.  However, Valve (makers of Steam) have openly stated their distaste for MSs marketplace and may delay creating a Modern UI version of Steam for some time.